How to connect a smart thermostat to newer boiler
I have a new (installed 1.5 years ago) HTP Elite Ultra boiler that is run with only a Red and White wire. I figured I would look into upgrading the default thermostat they provided so that I could access it via an app. I also figured this was a newer, more expensive boiler and should have a way to add a C wire, but I cannot see anything by looking at the manual (I have not cracked open the case to physically look at the setup yet). The wiring diagram is on page 47 of the manual here - and seems like it only provides a 2 wire setup. Am I misreading this? The boiler itself has wifi, but that doesn't seem to help me - even though it SEEMS like it would be a nice way to set up a wireless thermostat.
Any help in getting a smart thermostat setup on this would be appreciated

Looking further - since there are 2 thermostat settings I am wondering if I can use Pin 1 or 9 (whichever is not already in use) for the common - as it provides 24v per page 51.

This boiler uses DC thermostats, an AC thermostat may not work correctly.
That said on CN24 pin 12 is a DC ground and pin 1 is a +24 so you could try pin1 as R and pin 12 as C with pin 2 as W
